# Save a list as a single value in CSV and then reopen it as a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I can't modify a project that was all done in *CSV*, so I can't save and work as a *JSON* as it would be more correct.

So to save a list as a single value in *CSV* I do it like this:

```py
my_list = [[1.01,1.02], [2.01,2.02]]

with open('history.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    f.write('example_value',str(my_list).replace(',', '♫§'))
```

CSV file (`history.csv`):

```
name,list
example_value,[[1.01♫§1.02]♫§ [2.01♫§2.02]]
```

And to make this string back to being a list, when I rescue it, I do it like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

convertion = pd.read_csv('history.csv')
first_row = eval(convertion['list'][0].replace('♫§',','))
```

`first_row`:

```py
[[1.01,1.02], [2.01,2.02]]
```

I understand that saving a list in *CSV* is something not recommended, but as I am obliged to use it, I am looking for the most reliable way possible so as not to risk future use.

I would like to know if I'm missing something in terms of security in the model to save the values and if there is a safer method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `df.to_csv` method?

Here is an example.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as Df
Df([[1.01,1.02],[2.01,2.02]]).to_csv("your_list.csv", sep="\t")
pd.read_csv("your_list.csv", index_col=0, sep="\t")
```

And you can control the separator to "," (default) by `sep`.

Comment: Hello, I honestly think that this model does not correspond to the need, because when saving the CSV it does not make list turn a single value, it separates the index, each one becoming a separate value. And with the idea of saving newlines to the CSV as a record, it didn't return positively.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer If you wanna keep the list `[[1.01,1.02],[2.01,2.02]]` as a single value, you could put it into a list as an element, like, `Df({"key":[[[1.01,1.02],[2.01,2.02]]]}).to_csv("your_list.csv", sep="\t")`, then the first row will be `0 [[1.01, 1.02], [2.01, 2.02]]`